# Extract data from an HTML form using HTML Agility pack

Tags: c#, html, winforms, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to list all nodes in the HTML form I have dynamically using HTML agility pack, meaning that I don't know the names of the Attributes and the input names. 
The problem is when I want to get the label corresponding to the input.

```
<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
Username: <input type="text" name="user" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

So here I want to write Username then the input, it seems really obvious in this example but sometimes they're not direct siblings, there would be many hidden inputs, or other tags.

Another example:

```
   <input type=hidden name="startDate">

      <TR>  <TD bgColor=#008088 colSpan=2 class="headfont">

        <FONT color=#FFFFFF>  <B>* Enter ur username and password</B> </FONT>

      </TD></TR>

      <TR>

       <TD bgColor=#9ccdcd class="datafont"><FONT color=black>Username</FONT></TD>

            <TD bgColor=#9ccdcd class="datafont">

            <INPUT tabIndex=1 name=stuNum 

              autocomplete="off" size="20"></TD></TR>

          <TR>
```

Am using C# winforms in my project .

I have few ideas but they will take lots of time,so I thought since am new to HTML agility pack there would be a way or some shortcut to get it,,,Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any examples where the hidden inputs or other tags could get in the way? Will there be other text nodes that may be present but you want to ignore? I have some ideas here but I don't know if it will work for your cases.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.

```
static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, HtmlNode>> GetInputNodes(HtmlDocument doc, params string[] fields)
{
    var form = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//form");
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        var fieldNode = form.ChildNodes
            .OfType<HtmlTextNode>()
            .Where(node => node.Text.Trim().StartsWith(field, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            .SingleOrDefault();
        if (fieldNode == null)
            continue;

        var input = FindCorrespondingInputNode(fieldNode);
        if (input != null)
            yield return Tuple.Create(field, input);
    }
}

static HtmlNode FindCorrespondingInputNode(HtmlTextNode fieldNode)
{
    for (var currentNode = fieldNode.NextSibling;
         currentNode != null && currentNode.NodeType != HtmlNodeType.Text;
         currentNode = currentNode.NextSibling)
    {
        if (currentNode.Name == "input"
         && !currentNode.Attributes["type"].Value.Contains("hidden"))
        {
            return currentNode;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then to use it, just pass in the names of the fields you want to get the input elements for.

```
GetInputNodes(doc, "username");
```

Just a warning, it seems that HtmlAgilityPack doesn't close off the form like it probably should.  So you'll have to specify that form elements should be closed before loading the html.  Without it, HAP will not recognize that the form has any child nodes.

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["form"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;
doc.Load(url);
```

Comment: Thanks alot,but the problem here is that I don't know "username" it was just an example.